# How do I temporarily disable a CSS transition for a carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, carousel

I have an HTML/CSS/JS carousel with the following basic markup:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img1.png"></li>
        <li><img src="img2.png"></li>
        <li><img src="img3.png"></li>
        <li><img src="img1.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the following basic CSS:

```
.carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

    ul {
        left: 0;
        position: relative;
        transition: left 1s;

        li {
            display: inline-block;

            img {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the JS set up so that every 3 seconds, I change the `left` property of the `ul` tag by adding a negative amount of pixels to it equal to the width of the carousel so that it creates the carousel transition effect of sliding from one image to the next.

The problem I'm having though is related to what happens when the carousel reaches the end. I added a second copy of `img1.png` on the end, and when it gets there, I want to set the `left` offset back to `0` so that it'll start all over again and loop forever.

The issue specifically is that when the `left` property is, for example, `-1000px` and I change it to `0`, the carousel suddenly animates all the way back to the first image. I want to set the `left` property to `0` without the transition animation taking place.

I thought that if I temporary set the `transition` property to `none`, then set `left` to `0`, and then set the `transition` back to `left 1s`, then it would work, but it doesn't. It still animates from the end all the way back to the beginning when I set `left` to `0`.

How can I achieve the effect I want with CSS transitions and the `left` property, or is the approach I'm taking fundamentally wrong and need to be completely rethought? Thank you.

Comment: Just use two images: the one you're displaying, and the next one to reveal. Run the transition then change the src attributes of each image. Fewer elements and the logic can all live in a setInterval loop

Comment: duhaime, thanks for the response. That makes sense. However, once I run the transition, I still need to go back to `left: 0` don't I, or do I just keep incrementing the `left` property forever? Thanks.

Comment: You can just keep animating the same two items, as if you had two playing cards and kept sliding the top one off and placing it below the other. Slide the top one out of view revealing the bottom, set the bottom src to the src of the previous top, wait a moment, then repeat.

Comment: duhaime, that worked. Thanks for the advice. I still had to mess with the `transition` property a bit though to get things working. I ended up setting `transition` to `none` when the transition ended, and then setting a timer for `0` ms that then set the `transition` back to `left 1s`. It was the only way I could figure out how to get it to work the way I wanted without weird transitions occurring that I didn't want. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeehaw, well done! If you post your solution it might help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

duhaime gave a great suggestion to just have two carousel images at a time and always be swapping out the image paths.

However, I was still having an issue with the `transition` property animating things when I set `left: 0` to go back to the start. In essence, this is originally what I had and hoped would work:

```
// ulElem is equal to the ul element with the following CSS:
// ul {
//     left: 0;
//     position: relative;
//     transition: left 0.5s;
// }

ulElem.style.transition = 'none';
ulElem.style.left = '0';
ulElem.style.transition = 'left 0.5s';
```

However, that was creating the problem I was seeing. Since I'm using Vue.js, I thought that putting some of the code within a `this.$nextTick` call might do the trick. So I changed it to the following:

```
ulElem.style.transition = 'none';
ulElem.style.left = '0';

this.$nextTick(() => {
    ulElem.style.transition = 'left 0.5s';
});
```

However, that still didn't work. However, the following did:

```
ulElem.style.transition = 'none';
ulElem.style.left = '0';

setTimeout(() => {
    ulElem.style.transition = 'left 0.5s';
}, 0);
```

I've read stuff before about setting a `setTimeout` time of `0` ms and how that places it on the end of the call stack, which can help. Seems weird to me, but it works.

For anyone else that has a similar problem, this may be your solution. I'm not entirely sure why `$nextTick` didn't work, but I'm not familiar enough with the inner-workings of Vue.js to comment. All the same, `setTimeout` with a `0` ms setting worked. Thanks.